# Distance calculation with longitude and latitude has different results

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get distance of two locations, I really need this to be done with mySQL since I have to filter lot of records. Unfortunately the mysql statement results are different from google maps results. What could be the reason.

My Mysql statement is (Values hardcoded)

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN(6.914556 * PI() / 180) * SIN(6.913794 * PI() / 180) + COS(6.914556 * PI() / 180) * COS(6.913794 * PI() / 180) * COS((79.973194- 79.97330) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.609344 * 1000) AS `distance`
```

I get 74.27 meters as the distance.

Then I used another SQL statement I found and it gives 85.53 Meters.

```
SELECT (1.609344 * 1000 * 3959 * acos( cos( radians(6.914556) ) * cos( radians( 6.913794 ) ) * cos( radians( 79.97330 ) - radians(79.973194) ) + sin( radians(6.914556) ) * sin( radians( 6.913794) ) ) ) AS distance
```

But if I use google API

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=6.914556,79.973194&destination=6.913794,79.97330&sensor=false

I am getting 28 meters as the distance.

Is there anyway I can fix this issue. I need a solution to work at MySQL end. Appriciate all your support.

Edit:

I tried with PHP still I have that distance difference.

```
<?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } 
  else if ($unit == "M") {
     return ($miles * 1.609344 * 1000);
  }else if ($unit == "N") {
    return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
    return $miles;
  }
}

 function getDrivingDistance($inLatitude,$inLongitude,$outLatitude,$outLongitude)
    {
        if(empty($inLatitude) || empty($inLongitude) ||empty($outLatitude) ||empty($outLongitude))
            return 0;

        // Generate URL
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$inLatitude,$inLongitude&destination=$outLatitude,$outLongitude&sensor=false";

        // Retrieve the URL contents
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);

        $dataset = json_decode($jsonResponse);
        if(!$dataset)
            return 0;
        if(!isset($dataset->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->value))
            return 0;
        $distance = $dataset->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->value;

        return $distance;
    }
echo distance(6.914556,79.973194,6.913794,79.97330,'M') . "<br>";
echo getDrivingDistance(6.914556,79.973194,6.913794,79.97330);

?>
```

Comment: It could be that you're using a different (and less accurate) formula for the calculation - Vincenty and Haversine are the two main great circle formulae (Vincenty is more accurate but also takes more processing power to calculate), I'd imagine Google will use one of those... you're using a much simpler formula (the Spherical Law of Cosines) that will be less accurate than the aforementioned great circle distance formulae

Answer (score 4):

I tried Great circle formula and the result is 85.5m (your formula is not quite correct, but close). The different to Google is because Google try to calculate distance from two points on a road, somehow it is projected a point to the road. See the picture below. (The red line is plot from the coordinates, has a distance of 85.5m, the blue line is rendered by Google, somehow is 'snapped' to the road)
[image: The actual line is red has a distance of 85.5m, the blue line is render by Google, is 'snapped' to the road]

Comment: Is it just because this is more visual and easier to understand? Why are you so mean?

Answer (score 2):

The map link you provided has different latitude and longitude.

```
        "northeast" : {
           "lat" : 6.913845999999999,
           "lng" : 79.9733002
        },
        "southwest" : {
           "lat" : 6.913794800000001,
           "lng" : 79.9730488
        }
```

By using that in your query, it gives correct distance.